# How can I fix linter constructor error in react project?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, linter

I'm trying to reopen my react project and I have this following error message when I restart my application.

I tried to restart the project several times and try to understand what is a linter.

How can i fix this error? Where is my error coming from?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwsYP.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably due to webpack version issue,
have you tried removing node_module and npm install (`npm i`) ?

Comment: solving my problem, I deleted my node_modules folder and entered the command you suggested (npm i). Do you know how to fix the severity vulnerabilities after (npm i)? I entered the following command without success (npm audit fix --force)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).